# Hibernate Annotations : Many-to-Many relationship using Join table having common attribute in PK

Tags: many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to define a many to many relationship between two tables using a join table which has composite key, having a common attribute between the two tables?

Let's say, we have a table structure like below and am trying to define association between kit and business_product using kit_business_product table. Here are the table definitions (simplified for this question).

Table 1 : kit

PK1 : kit_id, business_id

Table 2 (Join Table) : kit_business_product

PK2 : kit_id, business_id, manufacturer_id, product_id, name

Table 3 : business_product

PK3 : business_id, manufacturer_id, product_id, name

Here are the java classes for these tables (simplified for this question).

Kit.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "kit")
public class Kit
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private KitId id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "kit_business_product",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "kit_id", referencedColumnName = "kit_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", referencedColumnName = "business_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", referencedColumnName = "business_id", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName = "manufacturer_id", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name", nullable = false)
    })
    private Set<BusinessProduct> businessProducts = new HashSet<BusinessProduct>();
}
```

KitId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class KitId
{
    @Column (name = "kit_id")
    private String kitId;

    @Column (name = "business_id")
    private long businessId;
}
```

BusinessProduct.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_product")
public class BusinessProduct
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private BusinessProductId id;
}
```

BusinessProductId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class BusinessProductId
{
    @Column(name = "business_id")
    private long businessId;

    @Column(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private long  manufacturerId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

With this code, I get the below given error.

```
[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 2017-03-17 14:17:54,767 ERROR com.common.DatabaseSession [] Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.hibernate.Kit.businessProducts column: business_id
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.hibernate.Kit.businessProducts column: business_id
at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:341) ~[hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:364) ~[hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
```

What would be the correct annotation for such a scenario? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!